# Magento 1.9 : create coupon code steps

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

I want to give 20% discount for each order up to Rs. 500, so that maximum discount amount will be Rs. 500 means no one will get more than Rs. 500 discount.

I want to create coupon code for this.

How should I achieve that?

Please help me.

Comment: Can you pls explain you question?

Comment: I want to create coupon code to give 20% discount for each order maximum discount up to Rs. 500

Comment: If customer add Rs.10000 product in your cart so discount Rs 2000

Comment: No discount will be Rs. 500 only.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Shopping Cart Price Rules

**Rule 1:-**

> Conditions > **If** Subtotal **equals less than** RS 2500
>
> Action > Percentage of product price discount > 20%
>
> Rule 2:-
>
> Conditions > **If** Subtotal **greater than** RS 2500   Action > Fixed
>   amount discount for whole cart > RS 500

Comment: Thanks, but I want to create coupon code for this discount. If I create 2 rules then how coupon code will work?

Comment: Not possible with standard Magento cart rules.  Have a look at Amasty they do 2 Promotional addons that may do this https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html and https://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html . Never used these addons myself but their support is very good and they do answer question fairly quickly.